# like and dislike review of a product by user in angular

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, mean

**user schema:**

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    review_likes :      [{type:String}],
    review_dislikes :   [{type:String}]
});
```

**review schema:**

```
var ReviewSchema = new Schema({
    productID:{type: String, required: true},
    numoflikes:{type:Number, required:true},
    numofdislikes:{type:Number, required:true}
})
```

**review controller:**

```
       .controller('reviewsController', function($route, reviewsFactory, $scope, $routeParams){
        var that=this;
        reviewid = $routeParams.id;
        productID = $routeParams.id;
        likestats = false;
        dislikestats = false;


    /*    console.log('controller',questionid)
    */    var getallReviews = function(){
        reviewsFactory.getReviews(function(data){
            that.reviews = data;
        })
    }
    getallReviews();


    var getProReviews = function(productID){
        reviewsFactory.getProductReviews(productID, function(data){
            that.proreviews = data;
        })
    }
    getProReviews(productID);
    $scope.pID=productID;

    this.addReview = function(){
        reviewsFactory.addReview(this.newReview, function(message){
            getallReviews();
            console.log(message)
            that.messages = message
        })
        this.newReview = {};
    }

    var getthatReview = function(){
        reviewsFactory.getthatReview(reviewid, function(data){
    /*            console.log('[CONTROLLER] That Question:',data);
    */            that.review = data;
            })
    }
    getthatReview();



    this.getThatReview = function(){
        reviewsFactory.getthatReview(reviewid, function(data){
            /*            console.log('[CONTROLLER] That Question:',data);*/
            reviewsFactory.checkRevLike(reviewid, function(response){

                if(response == "liked"){
                    data.likestats = true;  
                }
                else{
                    data.likestats = false;  
                }
                angular.forEach(that.proreviews,function(e){  if(e._id == reviewid)e.likestats = data.likestats; });

                angular.forEach(that.reviews,function(e){  if(e._id == reviewid)e.likestats = data.likestats; });


            })
            that.review = data;
        })
    }
    this.addlikereview = function(rId){
        reviewid = rId;

        reviewsFactory.addRevLike(rId, function(response){
            that.getThatReview();
        })
        }

    this.removelikereview = function(rId){
        reviewid = rId;

        reviewsFactory.removeRevLike(rId, function(response){
            that.getThatReview();
        })
    }

    this.checklikereview = function(review){
        reviewid = review._id;
        reviewsFactory.checkRevLike(review._id, function(response){
            if(response == "liked"){
                review.likestats = true; 
            }
            else{
                review.likestats = false; 
            }
        })
    }


    this.getThatReview2 = function(){
        reviewsFactory.getthatReview(reviewid, function(data){
            /*            console.log('[CONTROLLER] That Question:',data);*/
            reviewsFactory.checkRevDisLike(reviewid, function(response){

                if(response == "disliked"){
                    data.dislikestats = true;  
                }
                else{
                    data.dislikestats = false;  
                }
                angular.forEach(that.proreviews,function(e){  if(e._id == reviewid)e.dislikestats = data.dislikestats; });

                angular.forEach(that.reviews,function(e){  if(e._id == reviewid)e.dislikestats = data.dislikestats; });


            })
            that.review = data;
        })
    }
    this.adddislikereview = function(rId){
        reviewid = rId;

        reviewsFactory.addRevDisLike(rId, function(response){
            that.getThatReview2();
        })
    }
    this.removedislikereview = function(rId){
        reviewid = rId;

        reviewsFactory.removeRevDisLike(rId, function(response){
            that.getThatReview2();
        })
    }

    this.checkdislikereview = function(review){
        reviewid = review._id;
        reviewsFactory.checkRevDisLike(review._id, function(response){
            if(response == "disliked"){
                review.dislikestats = true; 
            }
            else{
                review.dislikestats = false; 
            }
        })
    }


})
```

**html:**

```
 <div ng-controller="reviewsController as revCtrl ">
     <div ng-repeat="review in revCtrl.proreviews>
         <div ng-init="revCtrl.checklikereview(review)"> LIKE
             <div ng-if="review.likestats" ng-href="#" ng-click="revCtrl.removelikereview(review._id)"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-star ">
             </div>
             <div ng-if="!review.likestats" ng-href="#" ng-click="revCtrl.addlikereview(review._id)"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty ">
             </div> 
             <span ng-bind="review.numoflikes"></span> 
        </div>
        <div ng-init="revCtrl.checkdislikereview(review)"> DISLIKE 
            <div ng-if="review.dislikestats" ng-href="#" ng-click="revCtrl.removedislikereview(review._id)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star ">
            </div>
            <div ng-if="!review.dislikestats" ng-href="#" ng-click="revCtrl.adddislikereview(review._id)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty ">
            </div> 
            <span ng-bind="review.numofdislikes"></span> 
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i'm trying to like/dislike a review in a list of reviews in questions

i want to limit 1 like/dislike to a review by 1 user

the problem occurring here is that in the display in html, the glyphicon successfully changes instantly but the span with ng-bind="review.numoflikes" and ng-bind="review.numofdislikes" is not instantly being updated but is updated on page refresh

the database is being successfully updated

also, if you could help me to restrict only like or dislike by user, it would be great. thanks.

Comment: I'm not going to check your code but only recommend some checks: (1) are the like/dislike properly bound (i.e. using `ng-model` within the HTML) to html elements? (2) Is the function that interacts with the DB known to `$scope` or `$rootScope`? As per limiting to one like/dislike, simply disable the buttons as soon as the user selects one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found a solution .. just try it once

```
this.getThatReview = function(){
        reviewsFactory.getthatReview(reviewid, function(data){
            /*            console.log('[CONTROLLER] That Question:',data);*/
            reviewsFactory.checkRevLike(reviewid, function(response){

                if(response == "liked"){
                    data.likestats = true;  
                }
                else{
                    data.likestats = false;  
                }
                angular.forEach(that.proreviews,function(e){  if(e._id == reviewid)e.likestats = data.likestats; });

                angular.forEach(that.reviews,function(e){  if(e._id == reviewid)e.likestats = data.likestats; });

                angular.forEach(that.proreviews,function(e){  if(e._id == reviewid)e.numoflikes = data.numoflikes; });

                angular.forEach(that.reviews,function(e){  if(e._id == reviewid)e.numoflikes = data.numoflikes; });


            })
            that.review = data;
        })
    }


this.getThatReview2 = function(){
        reviewsFactory.getthatReview(reviewid, function(data){
            /*            console.log('[CONTROLLER] That Question:',data);*/
            reviewsFactory.checkRevDisLike(reviewid, function(response){

                if(response == "disliked"){
                    data.dislikestats = true;  
                }
                else{
                    data.dislikestats = false;  
                }
                angular.forEach(that.proreviews,function(e){  if(e._id == reviewid)e.dislikestats = data.dislikestats; });

                angular.forEach(that.reviews,function(e){  if(e._id == reviewid)e.dislikestats = data.dislikestats; });

                angular.forEach(that.proreviews,function(e){  if(e._id == reviewid)e.numofdislikes = data.numofdislikes; });

                angular.forEach(that.reviews,function(e){  if(e._id == reviewid)e.numofdislikes = data.numofdislikes; });


            })
            that.review = data;
        })
    }
```