# prevent multiple clicks on like/dislike <div> in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**html code:**

```
<div ng-controller="reviewsController as revCtrl ">
 <div ng-repeat="review in revCtrl.proreviews>
     <div ng-init="revCtrl.checklikereview(review)"> LIKE
         <div ng-if="review.likestats" ng-href="#" ng-click="revCtrl.removelikereview(review._id)"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-star ">
         </div>
         <div ng-if="!review.likestats" ng-href="#" ng-click="revCtrl.addlikereview(review._id)"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty ">
         </div> 
         <span ng-bind="review.numoflikes"></span> 
    </div>
    <div ng-init="revCtrl.checkdislikereview(review)"> DISLIKE 
        <div ng-if="review.dislikestats" ng-href="#" ng-click="revCtrl.removedislikereview(review._id)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star ">
        </div>
        <div ng-if="!review.dislikestats" ng-href="#" ng-click="revCtrl.adddislikereview(review._id)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty ">
        </div> 
        <span ng-bind="review.numofdislikes"></span> 
     </div>
</div>
```

the problem occurring is that the user is able to do multiple clicks on the div which increases the likes/dislikes by 2 or more

how to disable this?

Comment: Can't you do a toggle in your function? Like if the `review` is already liked, make it `false` and vice versa?

Comment: can you give me a little bit of code, i'm new to this. thanks @Chinni

Comment: you can use the ngDisabled directive: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Comment: What does your `review.likestats` and `review.dislikestats` contain? Are they booleans?

Comment: yes @Chinni they contain true/false based on whether the review is liked and disliked

Comment: @Chinni also i need to restrict user to only like/dislike a review, not both.

Comment: Can you post your controller code of functions for liking and disliking the reviews?

Comment: @Chinni its posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38238401/like-and-dislike-review-of-a-product-by-user-in-angular

Comment: Please add the required code to the current question instead of referring to some other question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116647/discussion-between-utsav-bhagat-and-chinni).

Answer (score 1):

You can use two different div's one to validate and other to call function
in one div you can use like this

```
ng-if="review.likestats" ng-href="#"
```

and inside that div you can put other one to call function

```
ng-click="revCtrl.removelikereview(review._id)";
```

Comment: still the problem persists... it goes inside the div when ng-if is validated and user is able to call ng-click function 2 times if clicked in quick succession on the glyphicon

Answer (score 0):

try this. I'm not sure if this will work with your code. Give it a try.

```
<a class="toggle" data-stats="like">Like</a>
<a class="toggle" data-stats="dislike">Like</a>
```

javascript

```
var toggle = getElementsByClassName('toggle'),
    i;

function func(){
    setInterval(function(){
        var stat = this.dataset.stats;

        if(stat == 'like')
            // count + 1
        else
            // dislike count + 1
    }, 3000);
}

for(i = 0; i < toggle.length; i++) toggle[i].addEventListener('click', func);
```